# Fuel in the solenoid purge valve line

Tags: mazda-3, purge-solenoid

Today I was going to replace the purge solenoid valve in my Mazda 3 2006. I was having problems starting up the car every time after refilling gas. I in a post that the likely culprit was the solenoid valve and that it was an easy fix. First I disconnected the line on the front side of the car without issue. Then I disconnected the line on the other side (closer to the cabin) and noticed a little bit of gas came up. Not much but enough to wet my fingers (a few mL). Is this normal? I though this line will only carry gases and non liquid fuel. About 2 weeks ago the car started running with higher RPMs when shifting gears. It goes to 2000 rpms and if I hold the clutch it will go back to normal after 2-3 secs. Should I still switch the purge solenoid valve or if there is gas in this line do I need to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

OK this is embarrasing!! I pulled the wrong line. Whatever was the other line is probably the one that brings gas to the engine. I guess the lesson is do not try to do this late at night with very little light!

Comment: please edit this into your question do not post it like an answer or a comment.